# Django Cookie Cutter - postgres not found

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django

I'm following the book, "A Wedge of Django," and it uses the Cookiecutter template framework.  It says to check if postgres is running by entering `pg_isready` into the command line.  But `pg_isready` gives an error and `postgres -V` also gives an error, so it seems that postgres isn't installed or configured properly as it should be.

I've walked through each step in the book (chapter 19.3.3) and can't find that I'm missing any instructions.  I seem to be in the proper directory.  I can't move forward if I can't get postgres running.  Any help is appreciated.

```
(everycheese) joshp@joshs-mbp-2 everycheese % pg_isready
zsh: command not found: pg_isready
(everycheese) joshp@joshs-mbp-2 everycheese % postgres -V
zsh: command not found: postgres
(everycheese) joshp@joshs-mbp-2 everycheese % ls
CONTRIBUTORS.md         env.sample.windows      requirements
COPYING                 everycheese             requirements.txt
README.md               locale                  setup.cfg
config                  manage.py
env.sample.mac_or_linux pytest.ini
```

Comment: you should try to install & configure Postgres then configure the server settings to your Django setting.py file under the DATABASES={}. Try google to figure out how to configure Postgres on your system.

Comment: I know I can do a workaround, but creating a project with cookiecutter was supposed to install and configure Postgres automatically.  I'd like to figure out why it didn't work so I can use it more easily in the future.

Comment: Good point & best practice. good luck ...